# How to reuse/extend etckeeper's metadata engine for git control of non-/etc filesystems, or extend git natively with said capability?

Tags: linux, filesystems, git, metadata

## Update: 2020-09-22

After having used it a while (years?), [etckeeper](https://etckeeper.branchable.com)+git does not meet the requirements I seek.

## Overview + question

I want [etckeeper](https://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/)-like filesystem metadata control for non-/etc, git-controlled directories.  Home and web-app directories, among others, are classically sensitive to metadata (file ownership, ACL, permissions).  This can be extremely useful/important to employ git for [automated server deployment](https://web.archive.org/web/20121108151859/http://mig5.net/node/342) (along with tools like [Fabric](https://www.fabfile.org/)), among other things.  I would like to re-use etckeeper-like capability on said dirs, either with etckeeper itself or something else.

Can anyone suggest any tips/tricks/working solutions to provide either or both of the following:

1. apply the etckeeper engine (only care about the git-specific capability of etckeeper) to non-/etc, git-controlled directories. (Can assume at least Debian/Ubuntu Linux; would like MacOSX/[homebrew](https://brew.sh/) support if possible.)
2. extend git with metadata support (beyond over-simplified things like [git-cache-meta](http://www.kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2009/1/9/4654694)) to support an etckeeper-like capability or better?

## More details, background

There's a growing interest in [extending git with filesystem-metadata-control capabilities](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Tracking-file-metadata-in-git-fix-metastore-or-enhance-git-td6251248.html). [etckeeper's](https://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/) metadata "engine" seems quite powerful and reliable in my experience, and [etckeeper seems popular with others](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Tracking-file-metadata-in-git-fix-metastore-or-enhance-git-td6251248.html#a6282162) as well.  [metastore less so](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Tracking-file-metadata-in-git-fix-metastore-or-enhance-git-td6251248.html#a6282162) at least in part due to [metastore's non-text-based/merge-unfriendly challenges](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Tracking-file-metadata-in-git-fix-metastore-or-enhance-git-td6251248.html).  Further, etckeeper appears to have started with a metastore-based core, but then switched to its own (speculative?).

Obviously, this has OS/filesystem-specific dependencies. (eg, not trying to auto-deploy on Windows.)  Suggest an **optional** extension (if it's a "native extension") of git, enabled on-demand by the user with understood consequences of cross-platform breakage, such that native behavior doesn't break git's "by default" cross-platform friendliness.  Further, don't need to save extravagant unix/darwin/etc metadata (like ACLs); basic user/group/other perms and user/group ownership would be fine.  (These are the only things that are currently breaking things in my "security/vulnerability control/policies.")  Specific OSes I'm targeting up front: Debian, Ubuntu, MacOS 10.6+.  Later: Redhat's (CentOS, Fedora, RHEL), SUSE, maybe other Linuxes, and *BSD (FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD).  Don't see a need/application for Windows/VMS (even though VMS can be posix-friendly) or other non-unix-like OSes at any foreseeable point.

See also: background on pre-existing git, file-metadata/file-type tracking capabilities at [this stackoverflow question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521938/what-does-git-commit-mean-when-it-says-create-mode-on-stdout).

## Develop requirements for a new project?

Additionally: if anyone cares to develop requirements for such capability, I am sure that could prove useful, particularly for a new/uncompleted project to address above.

Comment: fyi. Found this Q&A on ServerFault: [Can etckeeper be used to track config files outside of /etc?](http://serverfault.com/questions/211425/can-etckeeper-be-used-to-track-config-files-outside-of-etc).

Comment: You could probably accomplish this using some (potentially sophisticated) [git hooks](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html).

Comment: Custom hooks: right, like with [git-cache-meta](http://www.kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2009/1/9/4654694) as mentioned above; useful, but an oversimplified solution.  Alas, looking to "push" this functionality beyond user-custom hooks into something "community owned" for better functionality/reliability/features/codereview/etc.  Further, don't want to write it from scratch, at least not by myself.

Comment: fyi. My question from stackoverflow: [What does 'git commit' mean when it says 'create mode …' on stdout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521938/what-does-git-commit-mean-when-it-says-create-mode-on-stdout)

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: I've heard of no movement, unfortunately.

Comment: @cregox - some reasonable answers have been posted. I'd still like to see native git functionality, but have not yet heard of any such thing.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/411512/41652), you just do this:

> It is right there in the [man page](https://serverfault.com/a/411512/41652).
>
> - Create a directory `/foo`
> - Initialize with etckeeper: `etckeeper -d /foo init`
> - Commit apply commits to the directory: `etckeeper -d /foo commit 'message'`

Comment: Quite interesting.  I can't find any etckeeper ports/tests running on Mac OS X.  Nothing in homebrew nor anywhere else substantial.  Anybody know of anything?

Comment: I'm asking etckeeper's suggestions for Mac OS X porting here: https://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/discussion/

Comment: @JohnnyUtahh: doesn't seem to have been any response from Joey or anyone else... have you made any progress on an OS X port?

Comment: @JohnnyUtahh: by the way, I found this: https://github.com/myint/etckeeper

Comment: @iconoclast I've done no work towards an OS X port, or any work on this project, for that matter. https://github.com/myint/etckeeper looks useful - thanks!

Comment: Update: my experience over the years has now taught me is that `etckeeper` is far from sufficient for what I seek.

Answer (score 4):

I digged in this problem and I decided to create a project [git-store-meta](https://github.com/danny0838/git-store-meta) for it.

git-store-meta is a perl script which integrates the nice features of git-cache-meta, metastore, setgitperms, and mtimestore. It should serve a good compromise of the flexibility, functionality, performance, and cross-platform portability and consistency.

Comment: I haven't yet found time to test and review git-store-meta, but at first glance it looks thorough, and quite promising. Quite appreciated. I very much look forward to testing this. Thanks again, @Danny Lin.

Comment: @'Danny Lin', I've referenced [git-store-meta](https://github.com/danny0838/git-store-meta) at my [related, stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8521938/605356).

Comment: My point of view: This solution (git-store-meta) is better than misusing etckeeper.

Comment: Update: I just looked over the README.md at [git-store-meta](https://github.com/danny0838/git-store-meta), and it looks _great_. I look fwd to having me or one of my team try this out next chance we get.